# Rake task: How to make task from another namespace prerequesite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, task, prerequisites

rake tasks allow to define a list of other tasks that need to run before as a prerequesite, i.e.

```
namespace :import do 
 task :products => [:environment, :tax_categories] do
   ... # create products from import and reference tax categories
 end
end
```

However, how could i reference the tax_categories task if it was defined in another namespace, like

```
namespace :init do
 task :tax_categories => :environment do
   ... # create tax categories
 end
end
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably do this, but dont know if this is the recommended way:

```
namespace :import do 
 task :products => [:environment, "init:tax_categories"] do
   ... # create products from import and reference tax categories
 end
end
```

Comment: Confirmed, it works. I'm happy. Thanks, now time to rake it away ;-)

Comment: then accept the answer by clicking on the tick icon near my answer, buddy ;)